# (ASK) Grep by Regex and read per line with BASH

Tags: regex, bash, solaris

I have couple of files which is

ocsmediation and
smsgwmediation

i use this script to extract and put the results in tmp.txt

```
for file in `ls -1 ocsmediation.log.$DATE-*`
do
    Get OCSID
    cd $DIRLOG
    OCSID=$(tr " " "\n" < ocsmediation.log.2011-09-19-00 | egrep "ocs[0-9][0-9][0-9]+")
    cd $CURDIR
    echo $OCSID >> tmp.txt
done
```

next i need to use result from tmp.txt as an input for my second script

```
cd $CURDIR
tr " " "\n" < tmp.txt


    cd $DIRLOG
    for file in `ls -1 smsgwmediation.log.$DATE-*`
    do
        cd $CURDIR
        cat tmp.txt | while read ID ; do

            SENDMSG=`awk '$0>=from&&$0<=to' from="$DATE $HR:$MIN" to="$DATE $HR:$MAX" $file | grep "$ID" |grep "Send" | wc -l`
            echo "$file: $SENDMSG: $ID" >> $CURDIR/sampl_send.$DATE.txt


        done 
    done
```

Now sampl_send>$DATE.txt is not created and there is no error..FYI tmp.txt consist of line like below:

ocsid143243324, ocsid34543543534, bla bla that's why i used tr to convert space into newline so i could read ocsid one by one (line by line)

i just didn't understand why i didn't get desired result (sampl_send>$DATE.txt)
oh the above script just snippets from my real scripts so you won't see standard line like

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
```

thank you

Comment: side note: you don't need 'for file in `ls -1 ocsmediation.log.$DATE-*`'... this can be expressed as 'for file in ocsmediation.log.$DATE-*'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cd` back and forth is extremely hard to follow. Your input files use relative paths, so they are "no longer there" when you change to a different directory, and also the (incomplete/invalid) result files are probably not where you expect them. But this is easy to fix; convert the script to not change directories, and/or use absolute paths to your files.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem is a quoting issue...

```
OCSID=$(tr " " "\n" < ocsmediation.log.2011-09-19-00 | egrep "ocs[0-9][0-9][0-9]+")
```

$OCSID will only contain the string up to the first character in IFS... if you quote it...

```
OCSID="$(tr ' ' '\n' < ocsmediation.log.2011-09-19-00 | egrep 'ocs[0-9][0-9][0-9]+')"
```

Then $OCSID will contain the entire string. Later...

```
echo $OCSID >> tmp.txt
```

This needs to be

```
echo "$OCSID" >> tmp.txt
```